# ASP .NET Min API Lambda Return PDF From S3 with SDK to Angular Front End - Only Works Locally

Tags: c#, asp.net, angular, amazon-s3, aws-lambda

*I am trying to download a PDF from an S3 bucket, routed through a Lambda triggered by API Gateway.*

My .NET Lambda queries an S3 bucket using the S3 SDK. The code copies the returned binary stream into a separate memory stream. Then, the code uses the fresh memory stream and returns a file from the controller. This works fine locally, but it refuses to work once pushed to the cloud.

Once the code is in the cloud, a file is downloaded to my frontend, but when opened the error message: "File does not begin with '%PDF-'" displays on the screen.

I work on a Windows machine in a predominantly Windows environment. The code behaves as expected when I run the Angular frontend and the .NET Min API backend locally, using two localhosts. The PDF always downloads.

**.NET Code:**

Controller:

```
 [HttpGet("DownloadPDF")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> DownloadPDF(string filepath)
        {
            /*
             * How To Contribute
             * Call the DownloadPDF function. Pass in your S3 bucket's name and the object's name, or filepath, you want to retrieve.
            */
            
            //Create a memory stream. 
            MemoryStream memoryStream = new MemoryStream();

            //Get PDF from S3 in binary form.
            using (var getPDFResponseStream = await _domain.DownloadPDF(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("bucketName"), filepath))
            {
               //Copy bytes from start position 0 to end position y.
               await getPDFResponseStream.CopyToAsync(memoryStream); 
            }

            //Reset the Position property to the beginning.
            memoryStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

            //Return the binary to the front end.
            return File(memoryStream, MediaTypeNames.Application.Pdf, "dummyPDF.pdf");
        }
```

Domain:

```
public async Task<Stream> DownloadPDF(string bucketName, string filePath)
        {
            /*
             * How To Contribute
             * The filePath string must equal the object name inside the s3 bucket.
             */
            return (await AmazonS3Service.DownloadObjectFromBucketAsync(bucketName, filePath)).ResponseStream;
        }
```

AmazonS3Service:

```
 public static async Task<GetObjectResponse> DownloadObjectFromBucketAsync(
             string bucketName,
             string objectName)
        {
            /*
             * Assume a valid IAM role with STS before making S3 call.
             */
            var becomeAuthorizedForS3 = await AmazonSTSService.AssumeRoleAsync(Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("roleToBeAssumed"));

            //Create an AmazonS3Client
            using AmazonS3Client s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(becomeAuthorizedForS3.Credentials.AccessKeyId, becomeAuthorizedForS3.Credentials.SecretAccessKey, becomeAuthorizedForS3.Credentials.SessionToken, Amazon.RegionEndpoint.USEast1);

            // Create a GetObject request.
            var request = new GetObjectRequest
            {
                BucketName = bucketName,
                Key = objectName,
            };

            // Issue request and return control to calling method. 
            return await s3Client.GetObjectAsync(request);
        }
```

**Angular Code**:

HTTP Service:

```
downloadPDF$ = (filePath: string | undefined) => {
    const url = `${this.basePath}${this.downloadPDFResource}?filePath=${filePath}`;
    return this.http.get(url, {responseType: 'blob'})
  }
```

Component Method:

```
downloadPDF() {
    let mockFilePath = 'sample_w2.pdf';
    this.taxService.downloadPDF$(mockFilePath).subscribe({
      next: (pdfDataLump: Blob) => {
        saveAs(pdfDataLump, mockPageLink) //npm i file-saver
      },
    });
  }
```

Attempted fix: I tried editing the the downloaded PDF in Notepad++, prepending the '%PDF-' to the beginning of the encoded string.

Result: Broken PDF with error message: "This file is damaged and could not be repaired."

To reiterate, it works fine locally.

Comment: I was able to get this working by turning the memory stream into a base64 encoded string. It turns out there are some funky things with API gateway and sending binary data. I couldn't get that working, so I just encoded the binary PDF data into a string. Once that string is returned to the frontend, I decoded it into a BLOB and used FileSaver.js library to download. Works fine now.